# CSS - Background images

Tags: html, css

Probably very silly question, but since I am trying to put my website online using my domaine which I have recently purchased, the background image doesn't seem to load at all.

Any idea?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("homepage1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Parisienne', cursive;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2.0em;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #B22222;
}

.homepage {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#welcome {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Schedule</a>
    <a href="#">Accommodations</a>
    <a href="#">Travel</a>
    <a href="#">Activities</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div id="welcome">
    <h1>Tracey & Jonathan's Wedding</h1>
    <p>16 / 08 / 2018</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your image file next to your .css file?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: the image needs to be located inside the css folder

Comment: I think your image folder is not going to right way please check the folder path. because when i used image cdn it will working fine 
https://jsfiddle.net/7bfkd3sk/

Answer (score 0):

The image is located in a folder and you must put the trail to get to the image so example -- background-image: url(folder name/folder name/homepage1.jpg); --- the folder name would be the name of the folders your image is located in. You can also do this as well --- background-image: url(../homepage1.jpg);

Here is the result when I added your coding -- good job by the way.
**Here is my coding to get this picture -- background-image: url(images/free%20images/pixabay/faucet-1684902_640.jpg);**

[image]

Hope this helped and if not please let me know

Comment: This is not an issue image will go fine with`" "` or `' '` :)

Answer (score 0):

**Folder Structure 1**

- index.html
- homepage1.jpg
- style.css

Then background-image url will be

```
background-image: url("homepage1.jpg");
```

**Folder Structure**

- index.html
- images (folder)

  - homepage1.jpg
- style.css

Then background-image url will be

```
background-image: url("images/homepage1.jpg");
```

**Folder Structure 2**

- index.html
- images (folder)

  - homepage1.jpg
- style (folder)

  - style.css

Then the background-image url will be

```
background-image: url(../images/homepage1.jpg");
```

Also compare the actual image name along with background-image url.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the css file location !
If it does't work, then press **F12** And select **Console** After that take a screenshot and put it here.

Answer (score -1):

Your "homepage1.jpg" should be in the same folder as in your "IDontKnowTheName.css". If it isn't, you can move it to there, or do "subfolder/subfolder/....../homepage1.jpg", or you can go a folder up by using "../".